# Trying to do multi auth using spatie laravel-permissions hasRoles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package

I am using Spatie Laravel Permissions to manage the permissions in my project and I am trying to use the hasRole() function for multi auth.
I am using if conditions to redirect users to different pages.
And its not working So Does some one have idea how to use spatie laravel permissions package to do multiauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read their documentation of guards?
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-multiple-guards